# How to register plugin step through CRM 2011 application

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to register plugin step through CRM 2011 application? I mean that, I have an entity. I want each record of this entity (on create) registers a plugin step.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate by detailing the reasons why you'd need to do this? I ask because there may be another way to handle your problem.

Comment: We have a plugin for auto-sequence on entities. Every time we want to add a sequence for an entity, we have to first register step on plugin and then create a record of auto-sequence. I think this is not good! And Im seeking a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CRM 2011 all plugin registration information is stored in dedicated entities

> Register Plug-ins Programmatically
>
> The key entity types used to register plug-ins and images are: PluginAssembly , PluginType , SdkMessageProcessingStep , and SdkMessageProcessingStepImage . The key entity types used to register custom workflow activities are PluginAssembly and PluginType . Use these entities with the create, update, retrieve, and delete operations. For sample code showing the use of these classes, see the Plug-in Registration tool source code.  [>>Source<<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg309620.aspx)

You need to create new SdkMessageProcessingStep record with correct registration information (register one step manually to check what information has been inserted to table)

Comment: Thanks MarioZG! This is what Im looking for!

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to use the plugin registration tool.

[Using the Plug-in Registration Tool for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237515.aspx).

Comment: Are you saying that there's no way to play around with some classes in the SDK en access/alter metadata to register assemblies/steps/images?! In a few weeks I'l be responsible for developing a programmatical way to do perform such an operation so it's a huge bummer if it's so... Please be wrong this time. :)

Comment: The later comments added context to the question I did not have at the time of answering. The question is "Is there any way to register plugin step through CRM 2011 application?", I took the application to mean the CRM web site, as in a user interface similar to that for editing forms and entities. The question did ask how to register a plugin programmatically. Ask a vague question and you will get vague answers, questions get the answers they deserve.

Comment: @JamesWood: But even taking the original question as is, it's *still* possible to register a plugin step through the Dynamics site using the API functionality that Mario described along with a bit of UI creativity, all while staying within the bounds of supported customizations. Your categoric "No" answer is not correct even under those initial terms.

Comment: Typo in first comment: "The question did **not** ask how to register a plugin programmatically."

Comment: @PeterMajeed, given the original question I still feel this is an acceptable answer.

Comment: @JamesWood - I'm not sure about acceptable/unacceptable, but regardless your answer is just wrong. The original question was "Is there any way to register plugin step through CRM 2011 application?" You answered: No. The correct answer is: Yes.